# How do I instantiate a C# service and use its data in a Blazor component

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-component

I am using Blazor and I am a beginner.

Currently I have several Blazor components that all need the same JSON data (data fetched from one URL, e.g., http://localhost/todo)

Instead of fetching the same URL inside all my components and duplicating my code, I decided to create a Service that fetchs the URL and share this service's output accross my components.

Here is the service, and all it does fetch a URL and return a JSON object (at least that is what I am trying to do)

```
using TodoApp.Models.TodoTestModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace Todo.Services
{
    public class Todo 
    {
        public string TodoURL { get; set; }
        public object result { get; set; }

        async public Task<object> TodoTypes()
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // HTTP header stuff

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(TodoURL).Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TodoTestModel>(responseData);

                return result;

            }

        }
    }
    }
}
```

The idea is call this service and give my components the output as

```
<TodoComponent ToDoResult="@result"> </ToDoComponent>
```

But I am having a problem when instanciating the object, e.g,:

```
@page "/"
@using TodoApp.Services;  
@inject TodoApp.Services.Todo Todo; 


<h5> List of todos </h5>


@code {
    Todo td = new Todo(); 
    td.TodoURL = ".." // does not work
}
```

In short I am trying to do the following:

- Instanciate the class
- Provide it a URL
- Get the JSON data (result) to pass it into my TodoComponent

Thanks for the help

Comment: What issues are you running into?

Comment: Dependency Injection is the way to go, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I can't instanciate the object

Comment: @CharlesHan That is what I was going for. The service was supposed to be a DI for the component

Comment: @Displayname can you share your DI setup code if possible?

Comment: @CharlesHan That is the DI code. I just create a service and try to inject it into my components. This is my first try so I may be wrong. I come from other languages so I know DI already. ]

Comment: Look at the lifetime of the DI methods. AddScopped Is not what you want. AddSingleton or AddTransient may be more suitable. I would like to point out this could be dangerous if it is a large amount of data. This is essentially held in precious server memory. Also whenever you do this sort of thing you have to maintain the integrity of the data with complex syncing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vaeon you can directly use client.GetJsonAsync and avoid the deserialization step in Vikram's example.The returned result set is not matching with the expected typeof List.

```
      var response = await client.GetFromJsonAsync(TodoURL);       
      return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code before `await builder.Build().RunAsync();` in the **Program.cs** file.

**Program.cs:**

```cs
...
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new 
Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

// Register services
builder.Services.AddScoped<TodoService>(); // <----- Add this line

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

**TodoService.cs:**

```cs
public class TodoService
{
  public string TodoURL { get; set; }
  
  public async Task<List<TodoTestModel>> GetTodoTypesAsync()
  {
      using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
      {
          // HTTP header stuff

          HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(TodoURL);
          response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
          string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TodoTestModel>>(responseData);
      }
  }
}
```

In **TodoComponent.razor** file, add the below code:

```cshtml
@page "/"
@using TodoApp.Services;  
@inject TodoService TodoService; 

<h5> List of todos </h5>
@if(todoList is not null && todoList.Any())
{
  <ul>
    @foreach(var item in todoList)
    {
      <li>@item.Name</li>
    }
  </ul>
}

@code {
    private List<TodoTestModel> todoList;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
      TodoServices.TodoURL = ""; // TODO: set the API url
      todoList = await TodoService.GetTodoTypesAsync();
      await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: @display-name Do you still need a working example?

Comment: yes that would be nice I could not get your code to work

Comment: @vaeon I have updated the above answer with a good example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your code is not working for me, specially the return section: see screenshot of the error here.  I only replaced instances of `Todo*` with `PullRequest*`. Anyway, the return section of the service is throwing the error. .. i am guessing it's serialization issue https://i.imgur.com/8ClUGYO.png see the image and let me know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

***Program.cs***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using BlazorApp1;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new TodoService());

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

***TodoService.cs***

```cs
namespace BlazorApp1;

public class TodoService
{
    public TodoService()
    {
    }

    public List<string> GetTodos()
    {
        //write your code here that fetches the todos using the TodosUrl
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    
    public string TodosUrl { get; set; } = "https://google.com";
}
```

***TodosComponent***

```
@inject TodoService TodoService

<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in Todos)
    {
        <li>@todo</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    public List<string> Todos { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        TodoService.TodosUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com";
        Todos = TodoService.GetTodos();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

}
```

Comment: when you inject a service with addScoped you already create an instance of it so you dont need to create a new instance for it

Comment: if you are gonna use async methods just override oninitializedasync instead

Comment: Thanks, I will try your code tonight after work

Comment: Thanks, but the  I replaced `throw new NotImplementedException();`  with my code I am getting some errors, https://i.imgur.com/nJxhTt5.png I don't know what to make of it.. I only changed Todo* with PullRequest* because the component names I gave in the question was for a demo. Anyway, the error seems to be related from something else